# Setting custom label in tag manager event

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We have two links on our page and want to record clicks on them using gtm.

```
<a href="..." data-gtm-event="register">Register now</a>
<a href="..." data-gtm-event="logon">Log on</a>
```

We have a trigger for clicks on elements that match the css selector of `[data-gtm-event]`.

And finally we have a tag set with uses the trigger to record a `Link event`. The trigger is firing and the tag is working.

But I would like to have a way to change the label on the recorded event to be either `Register` or `Log on` depending upon which link they clicked. In the past we made one trigger for each and one tag for each, but that isn't sustainable.

I know I can create custom javascript variable such as this:

```
function(){
   return "My label";
}
```

And then use that custom variable to assign the event label. And I do see that working.

Is there a way to make that dynamic?

I've found examples on the web for [using the dataLayer](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#events) but I don't want to add onclick attributes to my html elements.

Is there a way in the javascript variable to access the clicked element and get the value from its data- attributes?

I've found pages on using Macros, but that is the old version, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. If you enable the built-in "Click" variables one of them is "Click Element", which actually returns the DOM element with all it's attributes.

So in your custom javascript variable you can reference this and do

```
function() {
  return {{Click Element}}.getAttribute('data-gtm-event');
}
```

(maybe you want to check if the attribute actually exists first).

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it isn't working for me. I put this as my custom javascript variable and put that in the Label field for my tag. But in preview testing the tag fires and the custom variable is null. The attribute should exist, since the trigger is a css selector for [data-gtm-event]. If I just put in {{Click Element}} I get the href of the link.

Comment: And now that I said it didn't work...well it just started working. No idea why. Thank you for your help.